# Slide toggle a div on li click wont work in IE anymore (ie 9 specifically)

Tags: jquery

when I click on One (1) it just hides Two (2) and when I click on One (1) again, Two (2) reappears… repeat! It doesn’t pull up the sub-categories below One (1)

This works in firefox and safari for me but not in IE (9). i think it actually works in 8 but i dont have 8 anymore to retry it there.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kin-js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

jQuery(".toggle_container").hide();

jQuery("li.trigger").click(function(){
jQuery(".toggle_container").hide();
jQuery(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
});

});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<li style="padding: 4px 0 4px 0; list-style:none;" class="trigger"><a href="javascript:void();"><strong>One (1)</strong></a></li>
<div class="toggle_container" style="display:hidden;">
- <a href="#">1 sub 1</a><br>
- <a href="#">1 sub 2</a><br>
- <a href="#">1 sub 3</a><br>
</div>

<li style="padding: 4px 0 4px 0; list-style:none;" class="trigger"><a href="javascript:void();"><strong>Two (2)</strong></a></li>
<div class="toggle_container" style="display:hidden;">
- <a href="#">2 sub 1</a><br>
- <a href="#">2 sub 2</a><br>
- <a href="#">2 sub 3</a><br>
</div>

<li style="padding: 4px 0 4px 0; list-style:none;" class="trigger"><a href="javascript:void();"><strong>Three (3)</strong></a></li>
<div class="toggle_container" style="display:hidden;">
- <a href="#">3 sub 1</a><br>
- <a href="#">3 sub 2</a><br>
- <a href="#">3 sub 3</a><br>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Avoid void() in your links. Since you're using jQuery, use event.preventDefault() and attach a click event to your links.

Answer (score 0):

Frist of all `style="display:hidden;"` is wrong. Use `style="display:none;"`.

Your mark is invalid because of which IE is failing. You cannot have `li`'s without using `ul` and also you cannot have `div` inside `ul` i.e cannot be used as sibling of `li`.

Since markup is messed up calling `next()` on li, IE is returning the next `li` element so it is toggle the `li` instead of `div` as expected.

Fix the markup it will work fine in IE too.